# Server fires data twice - socket.io

Tags: reactjs, node.js, sockets, socket.io

I'm working on a web app where users can connect to a page and exchange messages locally using socket.io, React on the frontend and Node.js on the backend.

However, when a client sends a message to the server for broadcasting to everyone else, the server inexplicably sends the message twice to all connected clients. I've been trying to solve this issue but haven't found a solution yet.

client side :

```
import { useEffect } from "react";
import { getSocket } from "../socket";
import Input from "./Input";

const Home = () => {
  const username = localStorage.getItem("username");

  useEffect(() => {
    const socket = getSocket();

    socket.on("message", (msg: { id: string; message: string }) => {
      if (msg.id != socket.id) {
        console.log(msg);
      }
    });
  }, []);

  return (
    <>
      <div>
        <Input />
        <h1>Greetings {username}</h1>
        <div className="msghistory"></div>
        <div className="channelblock"></div>
        <div className="userblock"></div>
        <div className="channeltitle">EMPLACEMENT</div>
      </div>
    </>
  );
};

export default Home;
```

server side:

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const PORT = 4000;

//New imports
const http = require('http').Server(app);
const cors = require('cors');

app.use(cors());

const socketIO = require('socket.io')(http, {
  cors: {
    origin: '*',
  }
});

const activeUsers = new Map();

socketIO.on('connection', (socket) => {
  socket.on('newUser', (username) => {
    console.log(`user ${username} just connected!`);

    activeUsers.set(socket.id, username);
    socket.broadcast.emit('userJoined', { [socket.id]: username } );
  });

  socket.on('message', (msg) => {
    console.log('Message received:', msg);

    socket.broadcast.emit('message', msg);
  });

  socket.on('disconnect', () => {
    const username = activeUsers.get(socket.id);
    console.log(`user ${username} disconnected`);

    activeUsers.delete(socket.id);
  });
});

http.listen(PORT, () => {
  console.log(`Server listening on ${PORT}`);
});
```